# Rails ajax form on Firefox returns 406 not accepted - but only on second post request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm using Rails 3.2.3 and I have the following form

```
<%= form_for(@item, url: list_path, remote: true, html: {id: "item-create-form", class: "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %>
    <div class="input-append">
        <%= f.text_field :description, id: "item-description-input", autofocus: true, placeholder: "Type and press enter." %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

The create action with the following code:

```
def create
  @user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
  @item = current_user.items.build(params[:item])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @item.save
      @item.update_attribute(:vpos, 0)
      @items = Item.find_all_by_user_id(@user)
      @items.each do |item|
        item.update_attribute(:vpos, item.vpos + 1)
      end
      format.js
    else
      format.js {render "errors" }
    end
  end
end
```

The corresponding js.erb file is there and rendering as expected. Here's the code:

```
$('#position-zero').after('<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @item)) %>');
$('#item-create-form').html('<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "item_create_form", :locals => { :@item => Item.new })) %>');
$("#item-description-input").focus();
$(".best_in_place").best_in_place();
```

My application.js file looks like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery.purr
//= require best_in_place
//= require_tree .
// Loads all Bootstrap javascripts
//= require bootstrap
```

Everything works great on Chrome and Safari - only HTTP 200 responses.

On Firefox, however, the first form submission works ok. But the second one gives me a `406 not accepted` error.

Checking on Firebug, the content-type is set to `text/javascript` on the first request, but changes to `text/html` on the second one.

I've tried setting the content type after format.js (like so: `{ render content_type: 'text/javascript' }`) and also setting headers on the controller (like so: `headers["Content-Type"] = "text/javascript; charset=utf-8"`), to no avail.

Any good souls out there that can shed some light on this annoying problem?

Comment: do you mean submitting the same form twice?

Comment: Yes. It's a list, where you type in an item, press enter and the item is created on the list below the form field.

Comment: So it would seem that once you are submitting the form the form jqueryujs is doing something to mess up the next request. can you check if the data-remote attr is being modified after the first request?

Comment: Nope, data-remote is still set to true... :-S

Comment: would it be possible to see this in action somewhere?

Comment: Yes, please see it [here](http://scribblehq.herokuapp.com). Again, it only happens on Firefox (maybe IE/Opera, haven't tested). Chrome and Safari work ok. Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: so here goes the issue. notice the second line in ur js.erb? you are adding a form inside the form. so basically when u submit the form the second time, the first form is sent as the ajax request, however, the form above it is not, giving you the problem. you should remove that second line and things should be ok

Comment: Thanks, Amit! That's weird because, quoting the [JQuery API docs](http://api.jquery.com/html/): `"When .html() is used to set an element's content, any content that was in that element is completely replaced by the new content."` And it doesn't happen at Chrome or Safari. I'm not able to test it now, but I'll do it tonight and if it works, could you copy the comment as an answer so that I can accept it? Again, thanks a lot! Lifesaver!

Comment: the point is that anything inside is replaced. you not replacing the form wrapper, but the content inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

notice the second line in ur js.erb? you are adding a form inside the form. so basically when u submit the form the second time, the first form is sent as the ajax request, however, the form above it is not, giving you the problem. you should remove that second line and things should be ok

Comment: Thanks, Amit! Sorry my stupidity took so much of your time... :-S I added a div around the form and called .parent() so everything is now working.